# angular ionic http request sends null data to rest API

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm trying to send data from an angular form to and endpoint. 
This angular form is in a ionic 4 app. But all I'm getting is null data at the back end. But when I try the same with postman it works fine.I also tried changing content type to "application/json" but it also gave the same result. For the back end I'm using an php api.

```
// Http Options,where I set http headers
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
  };


// Create a new user
  createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http
      .post<User>(this.url + 'test/create' , user , this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(0),
         // handle error method is already implemented above     
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
}


I'm not receiving any errors in chrome console.
```

Comment: before your return, write a console.log(user); and let me know what you see

Comment: @devpato this is the output I get in console  " User {firstName: "Hasitha"} "

Comment: Try passing the value as a form data.

```const newUser = new FormData();
      newUser.append('firstName', user.firstName);

then in your post you pass newUser. ```

Comment: Why do you need the pipe? Can't you send the error from the backend as status 500 for example?

Comment: @devpato Thank you. There was an issue in the way I was taking inputs Not passing the value as a form data was the issue. Tried your way and worked. Thank you again.

Comment: @TomasVancoillie I'll look into it

Comment: glad it worked. I have added it as an answer. Please accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the data as a form data as follow:

```
const newUser = new FormData(); 
newUser.append('firstName', user.firstName);
```

Then in your post you pass newUser.